# Why do my registry writes report no error but have no effect?

Tags: delphi, winapi, registry, delphi-7

I'm trying to create a new system DSN entry when my service is installed. I tried to do this by writing to the registry via TRegistry.OpenKey and TRegistry.WriteString, but no values are being written. The first of the three keys that I'm writing to works fine.

```
const
  sODBCRegKeyLoc = '\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\OBDC Data Sources';
  sServerRegKeyLoc = '\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI\DSN Name';


rInstall := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE);
  try
    rInstall.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
    if rInstall.OpenKey(sRegKeyLoc, True)
      then
        begin
          rInstall.WriteString('Description', 'Monitors for new log entries. Allows modification');
          rInstall.CloseKey;
        end; //This call works fine.
    if rInstall.OpenKey(sODBCRegKeyLoc, True)
      then
        begin
          rInstall.WriteString('DSN Name', 'SQL Native Client');
        end; //This call fails with no error message.
    if rInstall.OpenKey(sServerRegKeyLoc, True)
      then
        begin
          rInstall.WriteString('Driver','c:\Windows\system32\sqlncli.dll');
          rInstall.WriteString('Server','serverIP\SQLEXPRESS');
          rInstall.WriteString('Database', 'Databasename');
        end; //This call fails with no error message.
  finally
    rInstall.Free;
  end; //Write values to registry.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following possible failure modes come to mind:

1. Your process has no manifest and so is virtualized. The writes succeed but the data lands in the virtual store.
2. Your process has a manifest but does not run elevated. The process is not virtualized. The attempts to open keys for writing under `HKLM` therefore fail but your code fails to report that error.
3. The process is 32 bit and so the access is redirected to the 32 bit view of the registry. The writes succeed but the data lands in the 32 view under `HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node`.

You'll need an application manifest to avoid virtualization. You need to use the `requireAdministrator` setting for `requestedExecutionLevel`.

Use `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` to specify access to the 64 bit view from your 32 bit program.

Comment: The 3rd one would make sense. The part that confuses me is that I can write to the first of those 3 keys no problem. It's only the two keys under OBDC.INI that fail.

Comment: Are you running the process elevated? Does the program have a manifest?

Comment: No to both. I'll try that when I get home, thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: In there is no manifest then item 1 applies. Your application runs virtualized. Virtualization was introduced in 2006 as a crutch to help migration from XP to Vista. You should not be running virtualized in 2014! You really do need to get on top of that.